# User-embedded YouTube videos not displaying

Tags: php, html

So I'm trying to implement a feature in my website which would let users embed their own videos. I've been using PHP for it since it's worked for me with other similar goals in the past.

```
$find = array("[video]","[/video]");
$replace = array("<iframe width='560' height='315' src='","' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>");
echo str_replace($find,$replace,"" . nl2br("" . htmlspecialchars($forumPost) . "") . "");
```

The two code halves were taken from the YouTube's "embed" option, and simply organized so that the user could put in whatever YouTube URL they wanted and it would display the video.

However, I came across a problem when I tested it with this embed code (taken from YouTube):

```
<iframe width='560' height='315' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/oPmUjjo02bg' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This test, oddly enough, works perfectly when I embed it directly into the source code, but leaves a blank box in the page when the same exact code is pieced together by PHP -- in this case, when I'd enter it in the forums like this:

```
[video]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPmUjjo02bg[/video]
```

I've triple checked that there were no errors in spelling or in the URL, itself, so it definitely has something to do with the fact that PHP is putting it together.

Nobody else seems to be having this problem, according to the internet, so I have to turn here, as I am completely baffled.

Comment: How does the php-generated code differ from your directly coded html? Look at the source and you'll almost certainly find your problem.

Comment: The only difference is that one is manually entered, while the other is made by the user, but it should be recognized as the same thing. Or at least, I _thought_ it should be. Clearly not, but I still want a way to make it work :/

Comment: There's clearly SOMETHING different in the code generated by the php. Otherwise it would work.

Comment: So you see my confusion?

Comment: What is the exact output you are getting from the PHP script?

Comment: I get an empty 560x315 block of space in the post where the video should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are not using the embed URL (http://www.youtube.com/embed/oPmUjjo02bg), but the video full URL (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPmUjjo02bg).

You'll have to change the link in order for the embed to work.

Comment: Oh, wow, I can't believe I didn't catch that -- thank you so much!